# Create new row if column value exists

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

[image]

I would like to iterate through column 3 and if an element exists, add a new row to the dataframe, using the value in column 3 as the new value in column 2, while also using the data in columns 0 and 1 from the row where it was found as the values for columns 0 and 1 in the newly added row:

[image]

Here, row 2 is the newly added row.  The values in columns 0 and 1 in this row come from the row where "D" was found, and now column 2 of the new row contains the value from column 3 in the first row, "D".

Here is one way to do it, but surely there must be a more general solution, especially if I wish to scan more than a single column:

```
a = pd.DataFrame([['A','B','C','D'],[1,2,'C']])
b = a.copy()
for tu in a.itertuples(index=False):         # Iterate by row
    if tu[3]:                                # If exists
        b = b.append([[tu[0],tu[1],tu[3]]], ignore_index=True)  # Append with new row using correct tuple elements.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without any loops by creating a new df with the columns you want and appending it to the original.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([['A','B','C','D'],[1,2,'C']])

ndf = df[pd.notnull(df[3])][[0,1,3]]
ndf.columns = [0,1,2]
df = df.append(ndf, ignore_index=True)
```

This will leave NaN for the new missing values which you can change then change to None.

```
df[3] = df[3].where((pd.notnull(df[3])), None)
```

prints

```
   0  1  2     3
0  A  B  C     D
1  1  2  C  None
2  A  B  D  None
```

Comment: Since my real df used strings as column names, I was having an issue with the columns being reordered when using `append`.  To resolve this I recorded the original column names as `df_cols` and then used `df = df.reindex_axis(df_cols, axis=1)` on the appended dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit more general (assuming your columns are integers and that you are always looking to fill the previous columns in this pattern)

```
import pandas as pd

def append_rows(scan_row,scanned_dataframe):
    new_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for i,row in scanned_dataframe.iterrows():
        if row[scan_row]:
            new_row = [row[i] for i in range(scan_row -1)]
            new_row.append(row[scan_row])
            print new_row
            new_df = new_df.append([new_row],ignore_index=True)
    return new_df

a = pd.DataFrame([['A','B','C','D'],[1,2,'C']])
b = a.copy()

b = b.append(append_rows(3,a))
```